# Formula to determine region

Tags: formula, account, territory-management

I would like to create a formula field in the account object to determine what Territory the accounts belongs to (East, West, Other) based on the account owner. I use Roles, so that would be cleanest solution if possible.
So 
if account.owner reports to Eastern Regional Sales Director then Territory = East
if account.owner reports to Western Regional Sales Director then Territory = West
Otherwise Territory = Other

How could i formulate that? thanks

Comment: What does "reports to" mean? Is that defined by `ManagerId`? That just gives you a `User` so you would still ultimately need to identify a field on the `User` object.

Comment: as defined by Roles. ie VP or Marketing reports to President (is under his hierarchy)